# Session expired within few seconds

Tags: php, session

I am very new to PHP. I am trying to develop a website with a database. It's all seems good till sometime before, but recently I am facing a very critical problem. After a successful login, within 5-6 seconds, the session is getting expired! I an unable to get solution for that, I have tried to change the session.gc_maxlifetime value, but it is not working! session.save_path is set to /tmp max_execution_time = 259200, max_input_time = 259200, max_input_vars = 100, session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Please help me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that?

```
$duration=60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // One week (in reality I think it does not last so long. 
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => $duration]); }
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355284/6062636), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227856/6062636). [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: Should I write those lines where I am starting the session [session_start();] ?

Comment: If yes, still not working! Getting expired in 5 sec!

Comment: I have check for other values too...

Comment: session.cache_expire = 180, session.cache_limiter = nocache, session.cookie_lifetime = 0, session.cookie_path = /, session.gc_divisor = 0, session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440, session.gc_probability = 1, session.save_path = /tmp

Comment: check if that are helping or not!

Comment: Update your question with the code you have. I wrote you the `session_start();` with parameters. It's the first thing that your script must do.

I suppose you have restarted the server.